# Помогите разобраться с параллельной отправкой http реквестов

Tags: асинхронность, java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема: требуется параллельно отправлять хттп реквесты, чтобы грузить хост. Реквест достаточно сложен и должен быть "собран" динамически для отправки. Подумал сделать это так: есть набор потоков, который генерирует запросы, и складывает в какую-то структуру (предположил, что `ArrayBlockingQueue`) и есть набор, который их оттуда достает и отправляет (в потоках этого набора есть отдельный хттп-клиент). Но тут задумался - раз структура общая, блокирующая, то 2 потока одновременно не смогут вытащить из неё реквест, следовательно, не смогут одновременно и отправить, даже если физически выполняются одновременно на 2-х ядерном камне. Можете, пожалуйста, посоветовать какой-нибудь более продуктивный подход. Спасибо.
Вопрос avp: потому что генерирование запросов занимает больше времени чем отправка, следовательно пока там что-то генерится ничего не отправляется и на хост нет нагрузки. В идеале нужно чтоб на 1 отправителя должно работать 3-4 потока генератора

Comment: 2-ой способ вижу в том чтобы и отправку и генерацию осуществлять в одном и том же потоке, но это не удобно, тк генерация может занять длительное время + для генерации опять таки прийдется обращаться к одним и тем же хранилищам данных, использукемых для составления запроса, а это опять синхронизация.

Comment: 3-ий способ - генерировать запросы в отдельном пуле(ExecutorCompletionService) - а в пуле-отправителе запросов забирать их через первый "готовый" Future , что скажете ?

Comment: 4-ое что пришло в голову - генерировать реквест в одном потоке, создавать Task, в который передавать этот реквест , и сабмитить таск в другой пул, в Taskе в run доставать из некоторого пула объектов (желаетльно не синхронизированного, пока не знаю какбы это реализовать) хттп клиент и через него отсылать реквест, после чего таск завершается.

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем связь между **вытащить** из блокирующей структуры и **отправить**. 

Действительно, вытаскивать запрос потоки будут по очереди (синхронизируясь на ArrayBlockingQueue), а далее что им помещает отправлять его уже не блокируя друг друга ?

Comment: Хочу по возможности избежать будь какой зависимости потоков между собой, так сказать обеспечить 100% параллельность. Нужно обеспечить *параллельную*,*постоянную* нагрузку на хост

Comment: Опишите подробнее в чем проблема с генерацией запроса,  почему Ваш 2-ой способ не подходит для распараллеливания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если вы уверены, что отправка из того же потока, что и генерирование данных невозможна, то сделайте несколько отправляющих потоков. Все они будут брать данные из вашего *BlockingQueue и засыпать, когда задач в ней нет.

Comment: Вы меня неправильно поняли :) У меня и так несколько отправляющих потоков, несколько генерирующих. Я по возможности хочу сделать так чтоб отправляющие потоки не блокировали друг друга при попытке получить реквест из *BlockingQueue

Comment: Это скорее всего невозможно. И не нужно. Время блокировки в этом месте очень мало и контеншн тут маловероятен. Так что не тратьте время на эту фигню.

Comment: Ок, просто хотел узнать мнение более опытных вэтом деле людей. Как бы они реализовывали такую задачу...Надумал ещё 1 способ - для каждого потока-отправителя - своя очередь запросов, в каждую очередь запросов запросы добавляют несколько потоков-генераторов. Что скажете ?

Comment: Это приведёт к плохой балансировке нагрузки между потоками-отправителями и как следствие может привести к ситуации, что у одного потока огромная очередь, а остальные простаивают. При этом проигрыш будет гораздо более существенным, чем потери на синхронизацию. Ручная перебалансировка - занудная задача и опять же небесплатная. И точно не lock-free.

Comment: Тогда что Вы посоветуте, как бы сами реализовывали? в 2 словах. Что скажете о способе с "Пулом по готовности" сп #3. Спасибо

Comment: Я бы скорее всего сделал бы через ExecutorService. Сделал бы класс-задачу, умеющую отправлять реквест. Сделал бы класс-задачу, умеющаую генерировать данные. И выполнял бы в разных ExecutorService'ах. Только надо продумать как ограничить возможность слать таски.. а то очередь на отправку может взорваться, если генерирование будет выполняться быстрее отправки.

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое за совет. Но почему очередь должна взорваться? можно ограничить размер очереди - допустим 200 реквестов, заполнится - потоки-генераторы заблокируюся пока не будет возможности добавить в очередь

Comment: А вам не уйти от синхронизации в любом случае. Только если будете слать запрос из потока, который генерирует запрос. Возможно, это на самом деле и есть оптимальный вариант. Его главное преимущество - простота и отсутствие синхронизации (почти, так как таймауты обрабатывать надо уметь).